# Use "estimate" for time duration

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

Can I use "estimate" to express a rough calculation of the time length? For example:

> Since all the materials are in stock, I estimate the two weeks' time is enough to complete this order.

Is there any mistake in the above, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, estimate can be used to express a rough calculation of time.

**estimate** (verb/noun)

Meaning: roughly calculate or judge the value, number, quantity, or extent of something.

However, instead of *the* it is more appropriate to use *that*.

> Since all the materials are in stock, I estimate **that** two weeks' time is enough to complete this order.